# hey i m new in ruby on rails and I get error while executing rails s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
ajay@ajay-Inspiron-9300:~/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http:0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport 4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Wellcome (NameError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport 4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise.rb:285:in `get'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise.rb:319:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise.rb:319:in `add_mapping'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:210:in `block in devise_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:209:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:209:in `devise_for'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This question isn't going to last unless you supply a lot more information. We need to see the code where the error occurs, and any data required to recreate the problem. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: as i remember, welcome word comes as default in routes.rb .look over that and post your code here

Comment: I think that the newbie can get this type of error..This is how one learn. Respect..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uninitialized constant Wellcome (NameError)`

Did you type "Wellcome" somewhere?  Perhaps in `/home/ajay/ruby_rails_practical_demo/ftuse/ft1/config/routes.rb`?  Error messages try their best to help!

Comment: yup i put wrong route .now i changed that line still this error comes./usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: The network address you're trying to use for the server is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

The app does not find a constant `Wellcome`. I guess this comes from a typo. Search the code for 'wellcome' or 'Wellcome' and fix that.